# When glucose production is low, the brain begins using ketoacids as energy... how does that work?

Tags: physiology, brain, metabolism, endocrinology, glucose

Can someone very generally describe how the brain consumes ketoacids/ketone bodies when blood glucose has been completely depleted?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Human body is a glucose driven machine which intake carbohydrates and converts to glucose. Energy is yielded from the glucose and glucose is stored as glycogen. When the carbohydrate intake is somehow reduced then body will shift its mechanism and uses the fatty acids to produce energy. Liver synthesis [ketones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ketone_bodies) from fatty acids in our diet or from body fat. Ketones(acetoacetate and acetone) are released into the blood, which is absorbed by the brain and synthesis energy from it through their mitochondria.

> The brain gets a portion of its energy from ketone bodies when glucose
>   is less available (e.g., during fasting, strenuous exercise, low
>   carbohydrate, ketogenic diet and in neonates). In the event of low
>   blood glucose, most other tissues have additional energy sources
>   besides ketone bodies (such as fatty acids), but the brain has an
>   obligatory requirement for some glucose. After the diet has been
>   changed to lower blood glucose for 3 days, the brain gets 25% of its
>   energy from ketone bodies.After about 4 days, this goes up to 70%
>   (during the initial stages the brain does not burn ketones, since they
>   are an important substrate for lipid synthesis in the brain).
>   Furthermore, ketones produced from omega-3 fatty acids may reduce
>   cognitive deterioration in old age.
>   [Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ketone_bodies)

When the body starts using the fatty acids for energy production, one problem arises in the brain and that is the blood-brain barrier( barrier that separates the circulating blood from the brain extracellular fluid in the central nervous system )Brain cannot use long chain fatty acids because they cannot cross the blood-brain barrier due to their bondage with albumin. As ketones are medium chain fatty acids which can effectively cross the barrier. So brain uses the ketones for energy production by a process called as [ketosis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ketosis). The ketone bodies are then incorporated into acetyl-CoA and used in the [citric acid cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citric_acid_cycle).

> The citric acid cycle – also known as the tricarboxylic acid (TCA)
>   cycle or the Krebs cycle – is a series of chemical reactions used by
>   all aerobic organisms to generate energy through the oxidation of
>   acetate derived from carbohydrates, fats and proteins into carbon
>   dioxide and chemical energy in the form of adenosine triphosphate
>   (ATP).
>   [Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citric_acid_cycle)

**Metabolic pathways to produce energy**

[image]

Comment: I've linked to your answer in [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21908/12102).

Answer (score 3):

Actually there is [fatty acid transport through the BBB](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21395585). Maybe the rate of this transport is not enough, I don't know, I think it does not really matter.

What really happens here, that the liver prepares the fatty acids, so the brain can use them more easily in the form of ketoacids to produce energy.

[image: fatty acid catabolism shared between the liver and the brain]

- fatty acid catabolism shared between the liver and the brain - [ref](https://thestrangeandspectacularworldofbiochemistry.wordpress.com/tag/ketoacidosis/)

Comment: What you tell is astonishing: you learn about fatty acids being prohibited from being turned into glucose. With this that doesn't seem to be true: fatty acids to Acetyl-CoA and then clockwise through the TCA cycle, left hand,  to Oxaloacetate, then pyruvate, then: glucose. It looks as if it is a matter of plentitude of carbon to burn, as by being shuffled through the TCA cycle CO2 two times is being set free.  -  Should be written in all the textbooks!

Comment: @PeterBernhard Yes, in the human body there is no fatty acid -> carbohydrate biochemical pathway or it is very slow (note that this is not true for all animals). Same is true for fructose and ethanol, that's why they cause oxidative stress, fatty liver and diabetes. I think many times you can prevent diabetes by avoiding fructose (pratically most of the sweet foods and drinks) and alcohol. I think this information about carbs and fatty acids is already in textbooks, at least I learned it in the university 10+ years ago. The fructose part is a lot more recent.

Comment: Pun on "prohibition"? I mean alcohol and fructose sound icy to me, take my excuses for my strange English, by the way; the graphic has a link but the ref does not tell about which book that the graphic is from. As it occurs to me...even in wording that question could have been me. Maybe my comment truly tells - not the whole "stuory fur" sure, as you mention fructose - so how does prohibition of fructose from being turned to sweet work? Can you e-"leber"ate?

Comment: @PeterBernhard Last time I read about fructose, it was something new and very logical. Now according to new reviews it is not as certain as it was. https://www.mdpi.com/2072-6643/9/2/96/htm https://www.mdpi.com/2072-6643/9/9/981 https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0168827818300667 https://academic.oup.com/ajcn/article/100/3/833/4576481?login=false https://scholar.google.hu/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=fructose+fatty+liver+review&btnG=&oq=fructose+fatty+liver

Comment: Again, thank you for clarifying what maybe is some common non having understood: e.g. medscape.com: "High levels of acetoacetate in blood may result from the following: Diabetic ketoacidosis and alcoholic ketoacidosis". As for me, I needed advice on that being the other dark side of the medal (no German) of ketose being needed. So, your shed new light on some, literally, half-knowledge. Diabetes, alcohol seem to imitate the need that must be: of calories, to starve is exhilarating. 
To sum up: with your answer "ketoacidose" becomes understood, it's good, not bad, it's regular.

Comment: "Last time I read about fructose..." - Fructose, interesting to know about that..., does not seem to share any "prohibition", thus beyond topic: fructose can easily be converted to glucose by the body, ain't right? Is there any preference the link you added (not very accessible for the common people?)  is about? Fructose might be preferentially turned to ribose of DNA?

Comment: "Last time I read about fructose..." -  Fructose, interesting to know about that..., does not seem to share any "prohibition". It can easily be converted to glucose by the body.  Is there any preference the link you added (not very accessible)  is about? Fructose might be preferentially turned to ribose of DNA? Some other item is  that insuline production does not react to   fructose input, fructose heightening blood sugar in diabetic and non-diabetic in the same way.

Comment: @PeterBernhard Just use the google scholar link and you can find many similar articles. Some of them are not paywall protected. These are scientific articles published in scientific journals. You can read them in libararies or in universities. Sci-hub is another way, but it is more or less illegal, it depends on country though. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sci-Hub

Comment: Yeah, it is "fruct"(verrückt in German, dialect I use) - to chat it all up: fructose does seem convertible into glucose. 10 years ago it's use in chocolate was considered anti-diabetic. In my thinking, there is a way to store away some fructose-elevation of blood sugar if not to glycogen, then in a very regular, i.e. non-insuline way as fatty acid in adipose tissure, and in my thinking your mentioning "fatty liver" is very valuable: glucose - like "starch" seems to correlate to glykogen and maybe white fat, and fructose, just extrapolative, to "brown fat". Guess you're not German too.

Comment: @PeterBernhard Looks like normally it is converted into glucose in the small intestine, but in big quantities it reaches the liver where it is converted into fatty acids afaik. from other studies. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6032988/ So consuming fructose as sweetener in big quantities (as we do nowadays with corn syrup) can cause health problems.

Comment: @PeterBernhard Another interesting thing here that it might affect cholesterol levels too. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0006294469900453

Comment: Mentioning cholesterol in that context seems irritating, I find it highly educating. Lately, I found myself "occuring" to me that cholesterol is either built into cell or veins' walls, however, cannot be burned, and - please help, correct me - cannot be converted into blood sugar. So, in that respect, cholesterol looks like some fat, and rightly suits this question.

Comment: @PeterBernhard The category is called lipid. It is transported with triglycerides and it is apolar, so we can call it fat. High level of blood cholesterol is problematic from atherosclerosis perspective.

Comment: I will say "lipid" not fat any more... So, I guess its trivial to know that cholsterol "cannot heat"...